# Using an image (in .png format) in the \thanks, i.e. last slide

Tags: graphics, footnotes

I want to include a symbol from a .png file as the \thanks-symbol. The code I am using is the following and used to work. I have not changed it since then but it does not work anymore.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{footmisc,graphicx}

\newcommand*\wine{\protect\includegraphics[height=.5em]{62343_a}}
\DefineFNsymbols*{woexl}{\wine \dagger \ddagger \S \P \| {**}     {\dagger\dagger}{\ddagger\ddagger}}


\setfnsymbol{woexl}

\title{Title\thanks{test}}
\author{Author\thanks{test}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

The error message is "Missing $ inserted. [\end]".

Interestingly, when using only one \thanks it works fine. So the following code works:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{footmisc,graphicx}

\newcommand*\wine{\protect\includegraphics[height=.5em]{62343_a}}
\DefineFNsymbols*{woexl}{\wine \dagger \ddagger \S \P \| {**} {\dagger\dagger}{\ddagger\ddagger}}

\setfnsymbol{woexl}

\title{Title}
\author{Author\thanks{test}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\DeclareRobustCommand{\wine}{\includegraphics[...]{...}}`

Answer (score 2):

This has little to do with using the image for the first footnote mark, but rather with the fact that `\dagger` is a math symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{footmisc,graphicx}

\DeclareRobustCommand*\wine{\includegraphics[height=.5em]{example-image}}
\DefineFNsymbols*{woexl}{%
  \wine
  \textdagger
  \textdaggerdbl
  \S
  \P
  \textbar
  {**}%
  {\textdagger\textdagger}%
  {\textdaggerdbl\textdaggerdbl}%
}

\setfnsymbol{woexl}

\title{Title\thanks{test}}
\author{Author\thanks{test} \
\thanks{3} \
\thanks{4} \
\thanks{5} \
\thanks{6} \
\thanks{7} \
\thanks{8} \
\thanks{9}
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

With `scrartcl` you also have to change how footnotes are typeset, or the mark would overlap the text.

[image]